# Accessing Page Field Value in content query web part

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a pagelayout which is having a page field(theme),user enters this theme.according to this theme the content of CQWP changes dynamically,in this CQWP there is a hyperlink in which i want to pass the value of this pagefield(theme) as a query string variable.
so can i access this value in contentquerymain.xsl

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using "PageFieldValue" token in your cqwp filter to filter cqwp results? Please follow [this](http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.no/2011/09/cqwp-pagequerystring-and-pagefieldvalue.html) link for some example.
Also if you want to pass some additional data to xslt transformation you can try to extend cqwp web part. Please follow [this](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/extending-content-query-web-part-with-custom-data/) link.